# How to fix gnome-control-center test speakers function? Failed to play sound: No such driver when tested. All other sound functions work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, gnome-control-center

I have lost the ability to test speakers in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. No sound is produced when trying the speaker test icons.  Expect to hear the Front Left and Front Right sounds.  Those files are present and can be played with aplay.

I have uninstalled, reinstalled ad nauseum all pulseaudio, alsa-utils and the gnome-control-center packages over and over and have not been able to reclaim this function.

Other than this test utility not functioning, all other sound functions work correctly.

If I invoke `gnome-control-center` sound in the Terminal, I can see the result of trying the test speaker icons which produce no sound output.

```
$ gnome-control-center sound

(gnome-control-center:9013): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: 16:36:45.345: Failed to play sound: No such driver
```

I found a similar post about this problem in a bugzilla.redhat.com post: [The speakers test in the Settings Sound does not work](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1562404)

In that case it was fixed with a gnome-control-center update.  But as mentioned, reinstalling the gnome-control-center package or resetting gnome defaults has not helped.

What can I do to get this "missing driver" problem for the speaker test fixed?

I also ran the alsa-info script so I hope that might point out something to somebody knowledgeable enough to understand the output.

[alsa diagnostic report URL](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4e644cc807ac8f391da91a1d0c61bfd5dba56ba1)

Comment: Found the solution and answer here.
[Audio is working, but the speaker test doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/a/1255244/875353)

Comment: Sorry for the posts.  Not familiar with the etiquette. First time using the resources.

Comment: No problem at all! High quality 'duplicate' questions like this work as signposts to help others find the answer like you did. Thanks for posting.